# Add password on redis server/clients

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, redis, passwords, redisclient

need some recommendations. I have the redis servers deployed in K8s and they are without the password/authentication. I need to work on adding the passwords to the redis servers and at the same time make sure that to the clients/services using that redis servers also get it. Has anyone come across this use case? #redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey for this purpose you should use a **Kubernetes Secret** that you mount into your redis container. It can be also mounted into different containers.

This would be my approach:

First, you'll need to enable authentication on your Redis servers. This can be done by modifying the **redis.conf**. you can provide a password in the configuration file using the **requirepass** directive.

Once you've configured Redis to use authentication, you'll need to update the Kubernetes deployment to use the new configuration. You can use a **Configmap** containing the **redis.conf** file, including the **requirepass** directive with the password you choose. Then Modify the Redis deployment YAML to mount the ConfigMap containing the updated redis.conf into the Redis Pod.

Next step is to store the Redis authentication password as a Kubernetes Secret and **inject it into the client containers as environment variables or volume mounts**. This way, the Redis clients can access the password securely and use it to authenticate. *You can define the secret with kubectl or helm.*

As last step perform an update of your clients and server Deployments and test out the solution.

*Please comment and I can provide you more detailed code examples. This is just a bit of how I would approach it.*

Comment: Does this answer your question or can I help you with something else?

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your recommendations. I am new to redis and k8s. If you have detailed code examples, that would be really appreciated. :-)